# Battery only charges to 99% and will deplete all the way to 0% if I am not careful

Tags: macos, macbook, battery

I have a Lizone battery installed in my mid 2010 MacBook Pro and have been having issues with Mac OS not allowing it to charge to 100% nor recognizing when the battery is reaching dangerously low levels. This is the second Lizone non-oem battery I have installed into this machine after my first one depleted to 0% and would not take a charge anymore (note that this occurred early in it's life - 60 cycles).

Has anybody else had issues with MacBook battery replacements acting like this and found a fix for the issue?

Comment: Are these batteries from a reputable Apple dealer or from an online marketplace?

Comment: @Mokubai Lizone sells non-oem MacBook batteries though Amazon and has very high ratings through that marketplace.

Comment: Considering how easy it is to crowdsource or otherwise buy fake product reviews (https://techcrunch.com/2016/06/01/amazon-sues-sellers-for-buying-fake-reviews/) I would not necessarily trust them.  If you bought one that didn't work as advertised then bought another then I'd be very suspect of them.  Memory cards were a high value and easily faked product and rife on eBay, batteries are similarly easy to make look real with a bunch of cells that were near dead long before their manufacturer though of putting an "apple" badge on them.

Comment: @Mokubai Fortunately I had a warranty on my battery so when the first one broke they sent me a second for free. Do you know of any reputable places where I can buy a new battery from without breaking the bank?

Here is a link to the Amazon page where you can find the battery that I am running currently: https://www.amazon.com/Lizone-Replacement-Battery-MacBook-10-95V/dp/B01LZGAW95/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1479408926&sr=8-2&keywords=lizone+mid+2010+MacBook+pro+battery